# autopostback for dropdownlist in mvc.net

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax

how to set autopostback for dropdownlist in mvc.net?

Answer (score 6):

You don't - there's no concept of 'autopostback', in the same way that there is no postback concept in the MVC framework.

If you want to submit the form, you can do that via javascript, if you want to update something else via a call to the server, you can set up an AJAX call, probably using jQuery to do so.

There's a bit of an example [here](http://stephenwalther.com/blog/archive/2008/09/07/asp-net-mvc-tip-41-creating-cascading-dropdown-lists-with-ajax.aspx).

Answer (score 5):

no jquery required. wrap each hidden id and dropdown in a form with the action to updateproduct. then its just:

```
@Html.DropDownList("id", (SelectList)ViewBag.Values, new { onchange = "this.form.submit();" })
```

Answer (score 0):

autopostback supports only in asp.net not in mvc.net, so you just need to write @Html.DropDownList("id", (SelectList)ViewBag.Values, new { onchange = "this.form.submit();" }) or jquery function in the cshtml file  script section.

Answer (score -1):

One thumb rule for MVC,
Any method of controller, on
 be called by JS or Jquery thru Ajax calling  routing.